# Use JAVA model classes in Python code

Tags: java, python, data-modeling, pyramid

I am working to build a UI that will be using a REST interface to an API server written in JAVA. I am looking into using [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) as the UI framework.

The UI and the API backend will be using similar data models, so is there a way to use the JAVA POJO objects in the python frontend? I would love to not have to rebuild all the model objects in Python if they already exist in backend.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: My using Jython is your answer?

Comment: You could use Jython, but then you'll almost certainly have other problems with library compatibility.  You could also try something like https://github.com/natural/java2python.

Comment: I think using Jython will cause more problems than its worth. I like the Java2Python idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not model the objects in a language-agnostic fashion, and then create for the language(s) of your choice ? Typically this creates value objects (so you have to write the behaviour for each destination language) but it takes a lot of the leg work out of this.

Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) would be one such example framework.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly the protocol buffers generate all the getters/setters for an object from an XML-ish structured text file?

Comment: That would be a reasonable summary, I believe